# Azure .NET SDK: Scale Azure SQL databases through SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I've just started using Microsoft's .NET SDK for Azure to manage some resources like SQL databases. I try using the [Azure.ResourceManager.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Sql) package for that purpose. I could not find out how to scale up and down regular SQL databases or trigger that process using the SDK - does anyone know?

I would expect this to be a method on the [SqlDatabaseResource class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.sql.sqldatabaseresource?view=azure-dotnet) where I can also access the current scaling level at the .data.sku properties.

As far as I understand it, the SDK covers the functionality of the Azure API, so I guess I could do it [through an API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/databases/update?tabs=HTTP), but as there is an SDK I would prefer to use it.

On [this Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-dotnet) it says

> Use the Azure SQL Database management library to create, manage, and
> scale Azure SQL Database server instances.

refering to the package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent which is deprecated:

[image: deprecated package]

The recommended replacement is exactly what I am trying to use - so how is it possible to scale databases using this SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out how it works. MS support suggested to set the `.RequestedServiceObjectiveName` property of an `SqlDatabasePatch` and call the `Update` method on the `SqlDatabaseResource`. Unfortunately, that does not work as that property is read only.

However, I tried it like I described below and it works for me. Lacking any documentation and the MS support not being particularly helpful I cannot tell if this is the "official" or recommended way to do it or if it will continue to work in future releases of the SDK, so I'm still open for better suggestions or confirmation.

So what you have to do is walk through Azure's hierarchy to access the database:

- Initialize an `ArmClient`
- Get your `SubscriptionResource`
- Get your `ResourceGroupResource` within that subscription
- Get the `SqlServerResource` within that resource group
- Create a new instance of `SqlDatabasePatch` and set its `Sku` property to a new instance of `SqlSku` with the `Capacity`, `Family` and `Tier` properties set accordingly
- Assign the `sqlDatabaseResource`'s Database ID to `SqlDatabasePatch.SourceDatabaseId`
- Run an `Update` or `UpdateAsync` on the `sqlDatabaseResource` providing the `SqlDatabasePatch` as a parameter.
- You can decided if you just want to trigger the database scaling (`Azure.WaitUntil.Started`) or wait for it to be finished (`Azure.WaitUntil.Completed`)

Here's the code:

```
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync("My_resourceGroup");
SqlServerResource sqlServerResource = await resourceGroup.GetSqlServerAsync("MySqlServerName");
SqlDatabaseResource sqlDatabaseResource = await sqlServerResource.GetSqlDatabaseAsync("MyDatabaseName");
SqlDatabasePatch patch = new SqlDatabasePatch();
SqlSku sku = new SqlSku("GP_Gen5");
sku.Capacity = 2;
sku.Family = "Gen5";
sku.Tier = "GeneralPurpose";
patch.Sku = sku;
patch.SourceDatabaseId = sqlDatabaseResource.Id;
var result = await sqlDatabaseResource.UpdateAsync(Azure.WaitUntil.Started, patch);
```

How to add/remove a Database from an ElasticPool:

Works the same way as above, just set the `ElasticPoolId` property of the patch instead of the `Sku`:

```
patch.ElasticPoolId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegropuname>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<servername>/elasticPools/<elasticpoolname>");
patch.SourceDatabaseId = sqlDatabaseResource.Id;
var result = await sqlDatabaseResource.UpdateAsync(Azure.WaitUntil.Started, patch);
```

Unfortunately, the `result` variable does not contain any success information. While I am aware that the `WaitUntil.Started` will not return the final result, it would be nice if the `UpdateAsync` would return the results of an initial check - like if it's even possible to scale the database to the requested tier.